# Electron app that opens a server or using sockets over the web

Tags: sockets, websocket, electron

Im making an app that multiple players can connect to, but im brainstorming the best approach.

Im going to be using electron for the interface and then be able to use other computers to log in to website to join the game with multiple players.

I will use sockets to connect to each player, but what i am trying to figure out is whats the best approach for the interface. 
Should i use express with electron to somehow connect to the same website the players are on?

Is it possible to make the electron app start up a server and have my website direct to the computer that is running the electron app?

Or my other option was to just continuously upload and download from a database, but I feel like that would not be very efficient.

Comment: By "use sockets" are you talking about use socket.io? It has the concept of "rooms" built right into the platform. I would advise against building into your app the ability to point your server to users' computers. It sounds like a huge security risk. You might also want to check out [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) which lets you sync database changes to multiple users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. I would suggest using a WebSocket based server / client architecture.

The server application is continuously running and handles inter-player communication as well as providing a database. The database could be integrated in the server application as a starting point, and, depending on your needs concerning scalability, be extracted as a standalone service in the long run.

Client applications could then come in many forms (a website, a desktop application, a mobile app). Using electron is a great way to enable cross-platform desktop application development that is adaptable to any of these scenarios, possibly also enabling to extract the contained web application as either a hosted website or even mobile application (using, for example, react-native or nativescript).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Okay so would using web socket based server cause security risk?

Comment: Not any more or less than any other process-connecting technology. If security is a concern, make sure you authenticate incoming connections and use SSL-encrypted WebSocket  (wss).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into that.

Comment: Sure, feel free to accept this answer when you feel your question was sufficiently addressed.